# Case insensitive check constraint in SQL database creation

Tags: sql-server, database, case-insensitive, check-constraints

This is my create statement. I need to make a `photo_filename` constraint for it to be case insensitive to accept and form of .jpg JPG, JpG, jpG, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE P_PHOTO 
(
    PHOTO_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PHOTO_FILENAME VARCHAR2(60) DEFAULT 'NOIMAGE.JPG' NOT NULL,
    PHOTO_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(2) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
    DOG_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT P_PHOTO_PK PRIMARY KEY (PHOTO_ID),
    CONSTRAINT P_PHOTO_P_DOG_FK    
        FOREIGN KEY (DOG_ID) REFERENCES P_DOG(DOG_ID),
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
CONSTRAINT P_PHOTO_CHK CHECK (UPPER(PHOTO_FILENAME) LIKE '%.JPG')

CONSTRAINT P_PHOTO_CHK CHECK((PHOTO_FILENAME) LIKE %[.]jpg')
```

Comment: Is the database using a case sensitive collation? If not, you shouldn't need to worry about case sensitivity. If it is, you might just need to add `COLLATE <some case insensitive collation>' to your constraint.

Comment: You've showed what you've tried, but you haven't explained why it didn't work.

Comment: `VARCHAR2` seems very Oracle-like. Are you sure this is on Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag)?